# android, applying Sepia filter in opencv

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I´m new in Android OpenCV and I´m trying to apply Sepia effect by using Mat kernel. I have a filter class implemented for applying filter in a source Mat.

This is the SepiaFilter class that implementes an interface Filter:

```
public class SepiaFilter implements Filter {

Mat mSepiaKernel;

public SepiaFilter() {

    mSepiaKernel = new Mat(4, 4, CvType.CV_32F);
    mSepiaKernel.put(0, 0, /* R */0.189f, 0.769f, 0.393f, 0f);
    mSepiaKernel.put(1, 0, /* G */0.168f, 0.686f, 0.349f, 0f);
    mSepiaKernel.put(2, 0, /* B */0.131f, 0.534f, 0.272f, 0f);
    mSepiaKernel.put(3, 0, /* A */0.000f, 0.000f, 0.000f, 1f);
}

@Override
public void apply(Mat src, Mat dest) {

    Mat tmpMat = src.clone();

    Core.transform(tmpMat, dest, mSepiaKernel);
   // Imgproc.filter2D(tmpMat, dest, -1, mSepiaKernel); not used
  }
}
```

This is an static method for getting a Mat from a file.
I´m using this static method in order to open all images with the same process. 
I´m not 100% sure yet about the color I should apply for **Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA**.

```
 public static Mat getMatFromFile(File file){
        Mat rgbLoadedImage = null;

        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());

        if (image.width() > 0) {

            rgbLoadedImage = new Mat(image.size(), image.type());

            Imgproc.cvtColor(image, rgbLoadedImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA);

            LOGD(TAG, "loadedImage: " + "chans: " + image.channels()
                    + ", (" + image.width() + ", " + image.height() + ")");

            image.release();
        }

        return rgbLoadedImage;
    }
```

And this is the call to the class:

```
mCurrentImgMat = getMatFromFile(fileImage);
Mat sepiaMat = new Mat(mCurrentImgMat.size(), mCurrentImgMat.type());

new SepiaFilter().apply(mCurrentImgMat, sepiaMat);
```

The last step is to get a Bitmap form the Mat:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.cols(), src.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(src, bitmap);
```

Once I apply the filter it is partially or almost all image white instead of the Sepia color. I´d like to know what I´m doing wrong. 
I guess it can either be the *Sepia Kernel* or the *Core.transformation*. I´ve  also tried with *Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA*.

Some links that I´ve been checking for getting an idea

http://answers.opencv.org/question/30328/how-to-implement-filters/

[Here mSepiaKernel](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/image-manipulations/src/org/opencv/samples/imagemanipulations/ImageManipulationsActivity.java)

Comment: your missing link is: [transform](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#transform(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))

Answer (score 0):

I think you got some mistake when you create kernel mat `mSepiaKernel`. The `mSepiaKernel` are 4x4 and you just set value to (0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0) but in this position is only one value not array (it is 1x1 mat), rememberd your kernel has one channel.
You need to change your code with below:

```
mSepiaKernel.put(0, 0, 0.189f);
mSepiaKernel.put(0, 1, 0.769f);
mSepiaKernel.put(0, 2, 0.393f);
mSepiaKernel.put(0, 3, 0.0);
```

and so on with others position in rows 1,2 and 3